# Avoid dashed border collapse in td/tr elements

Tags: html, css, border

any ideas how to avoid this issue when using border-bottom: 2px dotted black; in tables? 
[image: Any ideas how to avoid this problem, guys?]

CSS:

```
.plain-list tr td {
  color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #eee !important;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  border-top: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<table сlass="table table-striped plain-list desktop-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>test</strong></th>
            <th><strong></strong>test</th>
            <th><strong></strong>test</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using bootstrap 3 for tables.
Is it some known issue or there is something wrong with boreder definitions?

Comment: could you please share you table code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give a spacing of 1 like this

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
```

example : https://jsfiddle.net/ud2xj9fh/